# Group BY column and aggregate by column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by, aggregate-functions

I've a requirement, My Data look like

```
Customer   OpenBal  Qty  Date
---------  -------  ---  --------
707001304  597      -48  20100414
707001304  597      -30  20100415
707001304  597      -30  20100419
707001304  597      -54  20100420
```

I would like to calculate and get data

```
Customer   OpenBal  Qty  Date      ClosingBal (OpenBal+Qty)
---------  -------  ---  --------  ----------
707001304  597      -48  20100414  549
707001304  549      -30  20100415  519
707001304  519      -30  20100419  489
707001304  489      -54  20100420  435
```

Can help , how do I aggregate data on `Qty` by `Date` and subtract from `OpenBal` for day. `ClosingBal` for a day will be opening Balance for next day.

Please advise.

Comment: Can you give the table structure.. A tabular display might help to better understand the question.

Comment: Which database are you using?  MySQL, SQL Server 2008, Oracle, ... ?

Comment: HI Subir,Its actually sourcing from multiple tables. Regards,Shiv

Comment: Hi Andomar, Its Sql Server 2008. Regards,Shiv

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but couldn't you just add the columns with `+`?

```
select  Customer
,       OpenBal
,       Qty
,       Date
,       OpenBal + Qty as ClosingBal
from    YourTable
```

Comment: The original table contains the same `OpenBal` in every row. The OP wants it to be the previous day's `CloseBal`.

Comment: @AndriyM: Aha, I knew the question wasn't that simple.  Now the answer will depend on the DBMS I'd think

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
SELECT Customer, OpenBal, Date, SUM(OpenBal + Qty) AS Closingbal FROM Table_Name
GROUP BY Date, Customer, OpenBal
```

Answer (score 0):

> > The original table contains the same OpenBal in every row. The OP wants it to be the previous day's CloseBal

For Oracle 10g, 11g, SQL Server 2012 and DB2 9.5 you can use LAG function to access previously calculated value

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
insert into t_Customer values

(707001304,597,-48,20100414),
(707001304,597,-30,20100415),
(707001304,597,-30,20100419),
(707001304,597,-54,20100420)

select * from t_Customer

;WITH CTE as(select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Customer) as sno,Customer,OpenBal,Qty,date,OpenBal+Qty as clsBal from t_Customer)
,CTE1 as (
select sno,Customer,OpenBal,Qty,date,clsBal from CTE where sno=1
union all
select c.sno,c.Customer,c1.clsBal,c.Qty,c.date,c1.clsBal+c.qty from CTE1 c1 inner join CTE c on c1.sno+1 =c.sno 
)
SELECT * FROM CTE1
```

Comment: Good Day Anand, Yes It works. Many Thanks for timely help Regards,Shiv